# Do C# Collections work on all devices when using Unity3D?

Tags: c#, android, iphone, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity3D to build an Android/iPhone game. I was happily C# scripting while a dark thought occurred to me. Will C# collections like LinkedList and List still work on these devices ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they all work. Unity uses Mono as a base for its scripting engine. Mono is a mature implementation of .Net and basically all base classes.

You can at least assume everything under corlib, mscorlib, System.dll and System.Core.dll is included.

**Edit:** Ricky AH linked to [a page related to MonoTouch](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/about/limitations), which are probably also relevant for Unity's IOS platforms.

Comment: Although this may be correct today, you shouldn't assume all things in the Mono implementation used by Unity are available, as Unity Mono for mobile devices uses the AOT compiler which may have some limitations.

Comment: The restrictions where related to generics mainly, but since Unity now uses generics in their API that won't be a problem. MonoTouch uses the AOT compiler, and I have never heard it had such restrictions, it even is Xamarin's main product.

Comment: I remember reading some concerns about it in the Unity3D forums when they first launched support for generics, but I don't remember it clearly, so I'm probably wrong.

Comment: Just read this about limitations with generics with the AOT compiler. Not related, but i though it could be useful http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/about/limitations

Comment: I think those are a good read, since they will most likely apply to the same Unity platforms as where MonoTouch runs on.

Answer (score 1):

List works. 
Not sure about LinkedList, but it should.